# How to draw the velocity and acceleration diagrams if there is no connecting rod between the pins?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

[image]

From the previous examples I've seen, there is a connection rod, for example, between a and c and then another rod from c to one of the pins. However, in this case, the rod ac is directly connected to another pin? I assume there is no relative velocity in this case. Is this assumption correct?

EDIT: By pins, I was referring to O2 and O8. I've just realised that C is a slider. I thought it was a rigid 'pin' like O2 and O8. Sorry for the confusion.

So I think I know how to approach this problem now. Va is perpendicular to OA. Vc is a horizantal line from O2. Vc/a is perpendicular to the rod AC starting from Va.Then I need to intersect Vc and Vc/a to find the magnitude of Vc. Is this approach correct?

EDIT 2: I'm running out of time. I quickly sketched this to check if I'm on the right track.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alp, welcome to engineering.SE.  It isn't clear to me what you are asking at the moment.  What are the 'pins' that you refer to?  Can you please expand your question by [editing it](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/posts/2343/edit) to give it more context?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I think I know how to solve the question now. I'd appreciate it if you can double check.

Comment: That is great, how about you post the solution so the community can provide feedback. Welcome to engineering.se

Comment: draft solution added

Comment: You can check your results with forceeffect.autodesk.com/frontend/fe.html by doing a kinematic analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a vertical line at *C*. The instant center of rotation of the connecting rod *AC* is located somewhere along this line. To find the exact location, extend *OA* to intersect this line (below the slider). Now imagine a CW rotation about this point *K* will move the slider to the right and the crank perpendicular to *OA*.

[image: pic]

Now the relative rotation of *DB* to *AC* is at *B*. The [law of instant centers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation#Relative_centre_of_rotation_for_two_contacting_planar_bodies) means that body *DB* rotates about a point along the line *KB*. Since it is connected to *O8* at *D* the rotation center of *DB* is at *M*.

In the end, velocity at *C* is perpendicular to *KC*, velocity at *A* is perpendicular to *O2A*, velocity at *D* is perpendicular to *O8D* **and** *MD* and finally velocity at *B* is perpendicular to *KB* **and** *MB*.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have had the same exercise in school, maybe it helps, you just know $B= 1/2 AC$, and you know C is in horizontal line from 0.

If you  want the acceleration diagram let me know, but it is just the same.